# Evernote API: Can I get the remain monthly upload allowance bytes of my evernote account?

Tags: python, evernote

When we use evernote windows application, there is a Usage button. When we press the button, a new window would show up and display the monthly upload allowance remain size and the reset cycle time. Does evernote api support such function to allow developer to get the monthly upload allowance used size ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uploaded` in [SyncState](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_SyncState) is probably the one you are looking for.

> The total number of bytes that have been uploaded to this account in the current monthly period. This can be compared against Accounting.uploadLimit (from the UserStore) to determine how close the user is to their monthly upload limit. This value may not be present if the SyncState has been retrieved by a caller that only has read access to the account.

You can get it by calling [NoteStore#getSyncState](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getSyncState).

Comment: Correct. +1. I've added the description of `SyncState.uploaded` from the documentation.

Comment: Hi aneroid, thank you for update the documentation, I can read the data now  :)